# 12-15V to 9V power supply required to power audio equipment

Tags: amplifier, power-electronics, guitar-pedal, low-noise-amplifier

I have a 12-0-12 transformer with output after filtering 15-16V.
It's for audio equipment uses. I want to power a guitar pedal with 9V. I tried L7809 but it's making a whistling noise, so I tried LM317 with 820 ohms and 4.7k as R1 and R2 which is giving me around 9V.
When I play the guitar, higher notes work, but when I hit the bass side hard, a continuous noise is coming, like a drum roll which can only be stopped by disconnection power supply. I am able to run this with 9V wall adaptor and no issues. I need some way to power the pedals with the transformer. The particular pedal uses .52 mA as per multimeter.

---

Update : I tried 7v with Lm317 and it's working. How can it work with 9v on linear wall adaptor and not with 2 amp Transformer power supply 9v!

Comment: 0.52 mA (520 microamp) seems like an awfully small amount of current. Are you sure it's not 0.52 A?

Comment: are you using the required stability capacitors around the 317?

Comment: 520mA would get you about an hours use from a PP3 battery, so that would seem way too high.

Comment: Guitar pedals work with a 9V battery or an external power supply. The external power supply is just a transformer to feed 9V AC to the pedal's inbuilt power supply circuitry. Please check.

Comment: It would be immensely helpful if you post a schematic of the portion of the circuit in question. You can use the schematic button when editing your question. As other comments have suggested, there are components required for stability with voltage regulators.

Comment: Also you've written `.52 Ma` which isn't technically correct. You probably mean "52 milliamps" (mA). I don't think your pedal is using 520,000 amperes (0.52MA or half a mega-amp), nor do I believe it is using 520µA (0.52mA). Writing and formatting these units is important. Lower-case "m" for milli, upper-case "M" for mega. Volts, amps, and other unit abbreviations should be capitalized.

Comment: @KyleB How do you know the OP isn't here to learn _some_ EE? Schematics and correct units are important whether you're troubleshooting an audio device or an entire computer.

Comment: @JYelton  Because I'm a student of human nature   ;)